# How to window.scrollTo from another page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

i'm building a static page with gatsby.js.

My issue is:

I have a navbar with the function to scroll to a certain section of the home page using refs... I want to render the same navbar to other pages, this is why i've created a layout component.

However, when i'm in another page that is not home page, Contact link does not work as i have a contact section only on home page. What I want to achieve is when I click on contact link on nav and i'm not in the home page, the function redirects to home page and then scrolls to contact section, all at once.

Header component:

```
const Header = ({ scroll, contactRef }) => {
   return (
    <header>
    <nav>
        <div>
           <ul>
             <li>
               <Link to="">Home</Link>
             </li>                                           
                 <li>
           <a onMouseDown={() => scroll(contactRef)}>
              Contact
           </a>
            </li> 
                <li>
               <Link to="/portfolio">Portfolio</Link>
            </li>
         </ul>
           <div />      
       </nav>
    </header>
```

Layout component:

```
const Layout = (props) => {
    const contactRef = useRef(null);
    const scrollToRef = (ref) => {
        ref.current &&
            window.scrollTo({
                top: ref.current.offsetTop,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
    };

    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(props.children, (child) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, { contactRef })
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <Header
                scroll={scrollToRef}
                contactRef={contactRef}
            />
            {childrenWithProps}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to add the `id` attribute to your contact section and then the navbar link would point to `/#contact`. However, you would lose the smooth scroll.

Comment: Actually, there are ways to animate the scroll to a hash. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/c604vbrn/11/

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation